# how to validate the number of opened and closed tags?

Tags: php, html

I thought to do a preg_count for each `"/<[a-z0-9]+>/i"` and then count if exists the same number with the closed tags ie: `"/</[a-z0-9]+>/i"`

But I am not too sure. How would you count all opened tags and check if exists all closed tags?

Ps. i don't need to check for attribute and for xml `/>` single close tag. I just need a count on plain simple html tag

Thanks

Comment: this could more complicated then just that... depends on your goal... but "<div> </p>" is not vaild. neither is "<div> <p> </div> </p>". I would use a stack to solve this...

Comment: Are you aware, that in certain HTML doctypes, a single open tag is valid?

Comment: Not all (X)HTML tags have closing tags, such as `meta` tags in the `head`, or `img`.

Comment: Also, tags can/must have attributes, and your regular expressions will not manage to match something like `<img src="picture.png"/>`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629717/looking-for-light-weight-tool-api-scriptin-php-to-validate-whether-a-html-code for how to validate if a string is valid XML.

Comment: I don't care about xHTML, I just want html with closing tag validated

Comment: I don't need to validate attribute. MY html tag will be only <tag> or </tag> without attribute

Comment: Take a look at [HTMLPurifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/) if you need to sanitize HTML.

Comment: thanks but i don't need to purifier it. I just need to count tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote this handy functions. I think it could be faster if I search both opened/closed tags within one preg_match_all but as this it's more readable:

```
<?php

//> Will count number of <[a-z]> tag and </[a-z]> tag (will also validate the order)
//> Note br should be in the form of <br /> for not causing problems
function validHTML($html,$checkOrder=true) {
    preg_match_all( '#<([a-z]+)>#i' , $html, $start, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
    preg_match_all( '#<\/([a-z]+)>#i' , $html, $end, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE );
    $start = $start[1];
    $end = $end[1];

    if (count($start) != count($end) )
        throw new Exception('Check numbers of tags');

    if ($checkOrder) { 
        $is = 0;
        foreach($end as $v){
            if ($v[0] != $start[$is][0] || $v[1] < $start[$is][1] )
                throw new Exception('End tag ['.$v[0].'] not opened');

            $is++;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

//> Usage::

try {
    validHTML('<p>hello</p><li></li></p><p>');

} catch (Exception $e) { 
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Note if you need to catch even h1 or any other tag with numbers you need to add 0-9 within pattern of preg

Comment: I made a faster version with only one call to preg, if someone needs it just let me know

Comment: To handle void elements (hr, br, img, area etc.) this snippet will add the solidus character if it's not already there. Add the snippet in top of the function.
```$html = preg_replace('#<((?!\/)(?:area|base|br|col|embed|hr|img|input|link|meta|param|source|track|wbr)[^\/]*)>#i', '<${1} />', $html);```

Comment: The function as it is doesn't handle nested elements nor does it handle attributes in html elements. I have added an updated version here: https://pastebin.com/dpW0rK1w

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to validate HTML is using a HTML parser. Using Regexes to deal with HTML is very wrong - see [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: I don't need to validate html. I just need to count the number of opened tags (without attrs) and see if there are equal closing tag

Comment: check my reply I am using regex and I don't think any wrong combination could break the code

Answer (score 0):

My  case

```
function checkHtml($html) {
    $level = 0;
    $map = []; 
    $length = strlen($html);
    $open = false;
    $tag = '';        
    for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i ++) {
        $c = substr($html, $i, 1);

        if($c == '<') {
            $open = true;
            $tag = '';
        }  else if($open && ($c == '>' || ord($c) == 32)) {
            $open = false;
            if(in_array($tag, ['br', 'br/', 'hr/', 'img/', 'hr', 'img'])) {
                continue;
            }
            if(strpos($tag, '/') === 0) {
                if(!isset($map[$tag.($level-1)])) {
                    return false;
                }
                $level --;
                unset($map[$tag.$level]); 
            } else {
                $map['/'.$tag.$level] = true;
                $level ++;
            } 
        } else if($open) {
           $tag .=  $c;
        }
    }
    return $level == 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

ok, one solution would be:

```
function open_tags($page)
{
    $arr=array();
    $page // your html/xml/somthing content
       $i=0; 
    while ($i<strlen($page))
        {

            $i=strpos($page,'<',$i); //position of starting the tag
            $end=strpos($page,'>',$i); //position of ending the tag
            if(strpos($page,'/')<$end) //if it's an end tag
             {
                if (array_pop($arr)!=substr($page,$i,$end-$i)); // pop the last value inserted into the stack, and check if it's the same as this one
                  return FALSE;
             }

            else
            {
              array_push($arr,substr($page,$i,$end-$i)); // push the new tag value into the stack
            }

        }

return $arr;
}
```

this will return opened tags by order, or false if error.

**edit:**

```
function open_tags($page)
{
    $arr=array();
    $page // your html/xml/somthing content
       $i=0; 
    while ($i<strlen($page))
        {

            $i=strpos($page,'<',$i); //position of starting the tag
            $end=strpos($page,'>',$i); //position of ending the tag
            if($end>strpos($page,'<',$i))
                return false;
            if(strpos($page,'/')<$end) //if it's an end tag
             {
                if (array_pop($arr)!=substr($page,$i,$end-$i)); // pop the last value inserted into the stack, and check if it's the same as this one
                  return FALSE;
             }

            else
            {
              array_push($arr,substr($page,$i,$end-$i)); // push the new tag value into the stack
            }

        }

return $arr;
}
```

Comment: if $page is a string what count($pages) means for you?

Comment: I am sory, I meant strlen... I'm just used to treating a string as an array from other languages...

Comment: I would prefer to use a regex for this and not such high expensive solution

Comment: maybe you're right... I really don't know how efficient regex is... I'm not sure you could do this would regex, since you need to validate that they close at the right order (which I did)

Comment: hmm, let's not think about the order... but even with that i don't think with regex would be a problem because preg_match_all can save the offset

Comment: well, check out this answer and see if you want to use regex for this html parsing : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: your function has some logics errors: try it with this bad formatted html `"<a text text text text <p></p>"` Anyway i wrote a function you can see in the answer that doesnt' suffer any of those problems. And please next time you code don't put `{` in new lines. It's pretty/bad/old style of coding