# Show unmatched html tags in vim

Tags: vim

I've asked a related question here: [Show unmatched html tags in Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8744063/show-unmatched-html-tags-in-notepad)

Having only begun to use vim, I love it.  I love the fact that I can launch a file in vim and exclusively use the keyboard for editing it.  And, it's so quick and easy to do it once you get the hang of it...

Aside from all that, **I'm wondering if there's a way to highlight unmatched html tags in vim**.  I've searched SOF and also looked around the web, but I'm either not searching hard enough or nobody's posted how to do this or the ability to search for unmatched html tags in vim doesn't exist.

I'd like to focus on html tags in particular, but I'd also like to say that I'm looking for a way to show ANY unmatched tags in a document (tags being in the form of `"<SOME_TAG_NAME></SOME_TAG_NAME>"`).

Even if I could be pointed to a good tutorial on creating plugins for vim that would be helpful.  I would have made a plugin for notepad++ myself, but it requires the use of Visual Studio which I don't have.  I use open source technologies (particularly Java) for my development.  I'm assuming and hoping that vim doesn't require Visual Studio to write a plugin...

Comment: Surround.vim? http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1697

Comment: Vim has its own script language. But... Why don't you use a third party command-line software that detects errors in markup languages? xmllint for example can do it.

Comment: @Benoit - I've looked into xmllint and W3C's validator and they both are nice tools for validation, but I'm really just wanting to see unmatched tags in my documents.  I'll probably start using validator's more, but I'm just looking to see if vim can show me unmatched tags for now.

Comment: @manojlds - from the description - "The plugin provides mappings to easily delete, change and add such surroundings in pairs" - do you know if this plugin can search for unmatched tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [syntastic](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/).  When you run :SyntasticCheck or when you write, it will run a syntax check on the html and flag the unmatched tags.

Note: You will need htmltidy.

Also note, on gvim win32, you may need to edit syntastic's syntax_checkers\html.vim as mentioned [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/issues/68).

Comment: as i wanted to mention `syntastic` too i just add this comment - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168320/can-vim-highlight-matching-html-tags-like-notepad which could be of help to the OP

Comment: It appears that syntastic may be the way to go for me.  I've sent an email to Martin to see if there's a way to highlight HTML tags in JSP.  It doesn't look like JSP's are supported at the moment but I'll find out either way.  Thanks and +1 for you answer.

Comment: Though this isn't available for JSP yet, it does work on html.  Thanks.